# Getting several errors such as "Method 'Calculator::getNpsScore()' is not compatible with method 'NpsCalculatorContract::getNpsScore()'"

Tags: php

I'm getting errors such as...

> Method 'Calculator::getNpsScore()' is not compatible with method 'NpsCalculatorContract::getNpsScore()'

...for several of my public functions, for some reason. Specifically for everything from `getNpsScore` to `getTotalResponseCount`. Any ideas about that please? TIA

```
 <?php
 $responses;
 
 interface NpsCalculatorContract
 {
     /**
      * Creates an instance of the calculator provided an
      * array of responses (expressed as integers in the range
      * 1 to 10).
      * 
      * $this->responses = $responses; 
      * @param int[] $responses
      */
     public function __construct(array $responses);
 
     /**
      * Returns the Net Promoter Score rounded
      * to the nearest integer.
      * 
      * @return int $NpsScore Between -100 and 100.
      */
     public function getNpsScore(): int;
 
     /**
      * Returns the average score rounded to
      * one decimal point.
      * 
      * @return float $average Between 1 and 10.
      */
     public function getAverageScore(): float;
 
     /**
      * Returns the number of responses that
      * were promoters (==9).
      * 
      * @return int count($promoters);
      */
     public function getPromoterCount(): int;
 
     /**
      * Returns the number of responses that
      * were passives (==7 || ==8).
      * 
      * @return int count($passives);
      */
     public function getPassiveCount(): int;
 
     /**
      * Returns the number of responses that
      * were detractors (<6).
      * 
      * @return int count($detractors);
      */
     public function getDetractorCount(): int;
 
     /**
      * Returns the total number of responses.
      * 
      * @return int count($responses);
      */
     public function getTotalResponseCount(): int;
 }
 
 class Calculator implements NpsCalculatorContract
 {
     
     function __construct($responses)
     {
         $this->responses = $responses;
     }
 
     public function getCounts($responses)
     {
         $result = array_count_values($responses);
         return count($responses);
     }
 
     public function getNpsScore($responses, $promoters, $detractors)
     {
         $NpsScore = (((count($promoters) - count($detractors)) / count($responses)) * 100);
         return $NpsScore;
     }
 
     public function getAverageScore($responses)
     {
         $average = array_sum($responses) / count($responses);
         return $average;
     }
 
     public function getPromoterCount($responses)
     {
 
         $promoters = 0;
         foreach ($responses as $value) {
             if ($value === 9) {
                 $promoters++;
             }
         }
         return $promoters;
     }
 
     public function getPassiveCount($responses)
     {
 
         $passives = 0;
         foreach ($responses as $value) {
             if ($value === 7 || $value === 8) {
                 $passives++;
             }
         }
         return $passives;
     }
 
     public function getDetractorCount($responses)
     {
 
         $detractors = 0;
         foreach ($responses as $value) {
             if ($value < 6) {
                 $detractors++;
             }
         }
         return $detractors;
     }
 
     public function getTotalResponseCount($responses)
     {
         return count($responses);
     }
 }
```

Edit: I tried `global $responses;`, but that didn't do it either. I think I don't understand enough about the problem and am just taking guesses at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the "child" method has not the same signature as the parent method.

You can clear the intelephense error by including the variables used in the class in the interface. `<?php

interface NpsCalculatorContract
{
/**
* Creates an instance of the calculator provided an
* array of responses (expressed as integers in the range
* 1 to 10).
*
* @param int[] $responses
*/
public function __construct(array $responses);

```
/**
 * Returns the Net Promoter Score rounded
 * to the nearest integer.
 *
 * @return int Between -100 and 100.
 */
public function getNpsScore($promoters, $detractors, $responses): int;

/**
 * Returns the average score rounded to
 * one decimal point.
 *
 * @return float Between 1 and 10.
 */
public function getAverageScore($responses): float;

/**
 * Returns the number of responses that
 * were promoters.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getPromoterCount($responses): int;

/**
 * Returns the number of responses that
 * were passives.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getPassiveCount($responses): int;

/**
 * Returns the number of responses that
 * were detractors.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getDetractorCount($responses): int;

/**
 * Returns the total number of responses.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTotalResponseCount($responses): int;
```

}

class Calculator implements NpsCalculatorContract
{
function __construct($responses)
{
$this->responses = $responses;
}

```
public function getCounts($responses)
{
    $result = array_count_values($responses);
    return count($responses);
}

public function getNpsScore($promoters, $detractors, $responses): int

{
    $NpsScore = (((count($promoters) - count($detractors)) / count($responses)) * 100);
    return $NpsScore;
}

public function getAverageScore($responses): float
 {
     $average = array_sum($responses) / count($responses);
     return $average;
 }

 public function getPromoterCount($responses): int
 {

     $promoters = 0;
     foreach ($responses as $value) {
         if ($value === 9) {
             $promoters++;
         }
     }
     return $promoters;
 }

 public function getPassiveCount($responses): int
 {

     $passives = 0;
     foreach ($responses as $value) {
         if ($value === 7 || $value === 8) {
             $passives++;
         }
     }
     return $passives;
 }

 public function getDetractorCount($responses): int
 {

     $detractors = 0;
     foreach ($responses as $value) {
         if ($value < 6) {
             $detractors++;
         }
     }
     return $detractors;
 }

 public function getTotalResponseCount($responses): int
 {
     return count($responses);
 }
```

}
`

Comment: That's great, thanks very much! If you (or anyone else) can explain a bit more about what that is actually doing, that would be appreciated. This certainly clears the error in any case, so thanks again! :)